# phpword downloading document through browser

Tags: json, yii, phpword

I am trying to download this document but I am having some issues. I can create and save it fine but errors pop up when trying to output it on browser.

```
The file xxx.docx cannot be opened because there are problems with the contents.
```

followed by

```
Word found unreadable content in xxx.docx. Do you want to recover the contents of this document?
```

i click yes, then follows

```
this file cannot be opened using Microsoft Word.
```

I click open and it opens fine with no problems. If i browse to where the file is stored and open it it opens fine, so i believe i have the headers set wrong?

```
// Saving the document as OOXML file...
        $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
        $objWriter->save(Yii::app()->params['exportToDir'].$filename.".docx");
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '.docx"');
        //header("Content-Type: application/docx");
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header("Cache-Control: public");
        header('Expires: 0');
        $objWriter->save("php://output");
```

The following works for Excel. it is a json request

```
$filename = "InvoiceSummaryReport_".date("Y-m", strtotime($datestr)) . "_" . date('Y-m-d_H-i-s_T').".xls";
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"');
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
        // If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

        // If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
        //header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
        header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
        header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
        header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
        $objWriter->save(Yii::app()->params['exportToDir'].$filename);

        echo "reports/$filename";
```

trying to replicate for word, but it does not work

```
$filename = "Weekly-MC-Report-" . date('d_F_Y').".docx" ;
        // Saving the document as OOXML file...
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Expires: 0');

        $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
        $objWriter->save(Yii::app()->params['exportToDir'].$filename);      
        echo "reports/$filename";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only differing thing to my working definition (below) is the cache-control part, i.e. you could try with these (at least for identifying the row causing your headaches even if you would be trying to have some caching for your generated documents)...

```
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $file . '"');
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Expires: 0');

    $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($PHPWord, 'Word2007');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
```